# Oracle 11g View resultset of table from Stored procedure in Toad

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am a novice to Oracle 11g and would like to view the resultset of a table output from a stored procedure. I have created the procedure and executed it. I just want to view the output in the form of a grid like in SQL Server. Please help me out.

This is the declaration of my procedure:

**Spec:**

```
TYPE ret_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
procedure get_data(
p_start_dt in varchar2, 
p_end_dt in varchar2, 
p_results out ret_cursor,
p_err_no out number,
p_err_msg out varchar2
);
```

**Body:**

```
PROCEDURE get_data(
      p_start_dt    IN      VARCHAR2, 
      p_end_dt      IN      VARCHAR2, 
      p_results     OUT     ret_cursor,
      p_err_no      OUT     NUMBER,
      p_err_msg     OUT     VARCHAR2
   )
```

Comment: :Which tool you are using to execute the procedure ,and what is the declaration of your procedure.

Comment: Am using Toad as I have mentioned in my title. Please help

Comment: :check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are using TOAD ,then its very easy to see output of refcursor .

1. First copy below code in Toad Editor

   ```
   DECLARE
    v_err_no number;
    v_err_msg VARCHAR2(200);
   BEGIN
   get_data(
      p_start_dt    =>  SYSDATE,      --depend on you
      p_end_dt      => SYSDATE+10,    --depend on you
      p_results     =>   :ret_cursor,
      p_err_no      =>   v_err_no,
      p_err_msg     =>   v_err_msg
      );
   --print error message   
   END;
   ```
2. Now goto Editor-->Execute Statement f9 ,and click
3. Popup appear ,and asking you for ret_cursor type,select type as cursor ,do as shown below in the screenshot

[image: select type of refcursor]

- Click OK ,and then you can see result in the datagrid .

Answer (score 0):

If you want simply look at the result you can use SQL*Plus and it's REFCURSOR bind variable and PRINT command:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p
  2  (
  3    x out sys_refcursor
  4  )
  5  is
  6  begin
  7    open x for select 1 a, 'a' b from dual;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> exec p(:rc)

PL/SQL procedure completed.

SQL> print rc

         A B                                                                    
---------- -                                                                    
         1 a
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to view the output in the form of a grid in Toad GUI?